# backtrack: How can I change the following code

Tags: python, backtracking

How can I change the following code so that I don't have to pass set1 and set2 to the function?

This function finds if the array can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is equal.

```
def canPartition(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        def backtrack(i, set1, set2):
            if i == len(nums):
                if set1 == set2:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            
            path1 = backtrack(i+1, set1 + nums[i], set2)
            path2 = backtrack(i+1, set1, set2 + nums[i])
            return path1 or path2
            
        return backtrack(0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean, "in the original call".  Just use default parameters.

```
def canPartition(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    def backtrack(i, set1=0, set2=0):
        if i == len(nums):
            return set1 == set2
        
        path1 = backtrack(i+1, set1 + nums[i], set2)
        path2 = backtrack(i+1, set1, set2 + nums[i])
        return path1 or path2
            
    return backtrack(0)
```